# How can I detect whether a variable exists in Flask session?

Tags: flask

I would like to detect if a session['logged_in'] key exists, which means my user has already logged in.

For Example:

```
if (session['logged_in'] != None):
    if session['logged_in'] == True:
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

However, if the key 'logged_in' doesnt exist it therefore generates an error. As a session object is like a dictionary I thought I would be able to use the had_key() method, but this doesn't seem to work either. Is there an easy way to detect if a session contains data without generating an error?

Comment: There are better ways to check if a user is logged in...Is that your actual use case?

Comment: `if session.get("logged_in", False) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` keyword for `keys` method:

```
# Check if key exists
if 'logged_in' in session.keys():
    if session['logged_in'] == True:
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

Answer (score 18):

In general, accessing session items is as simple as using a dictionary.

You could use `has_key()` (there is no `had_key()` method), but it would be better to use `in` or `get()`. An example flask app that accesses session items:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if session.get('logged_in') == True:
        return 'You are logged in'
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    session['logged_in'] = True
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'ssssshhhhh'
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this to check if a key exists in the session dict:

```
if session.get('logged_in'):
    if session['logged_in']:
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if session.get('logged_in') is not None:
    # do something for logged in user
    return render_template('success.html')
else:
    # do something for non-logged in user
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Give that a try, it should work.

Sorry for the belated answer, but was struggling upon the same things myself and this is the basic formula.

In my scenario, I have a `users` table in a mysql database, by which when a user logs in or creates an account, a `session` variable is created and set to that user's `id`.

If this user now navigates to root `('/')`, the `session` variable is detected and the `success.html` is served.

If no value for `session['logged_in']` is found, than `index.html` is served, where they can create an account or login.

Answer (score 4):

As [@rnevius mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925602/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-variable-exists-in-flask-session#comment46107522_28925602), if the underlying issue you are trying to solve is testing to see if the current user is logged in then you might be better off using some [built-in Flask functionality](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions).

If you are just trying to find out if a certain key (`logged_in`) exists within the session object, you can treat the session object as if it was a dictionary and simply use the following syntax:

```
if session.get('logged_in') is not None:
  # Here we know that a logged_in key is present in the session object.
  # Now we can safely check it's value
  if session['logged_in'] == True:
      return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

Comment: So the get() method doesnt generate an error, excellent, thanks muchly :)

Comment: @brad You are correct.  However it's not really that it doesn't generate an error - if the key doesn't exist, `get` will return a default value: `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Check if key exists
if session.get("key") == None:
    # Do something if it doesnt exist
else:
    # Do something else if it does exist
```